# AWS Redundant site to site vpn with multiple customer gateways

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to setup an AWS site to site VPN with multiple customer gateways. I'm going through the following document - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/vpn-redundant-connection.html

[image]

I'm unclear whether I can get this accomplished without BGP. I currently only have static routes available to me. Can multiple redundant customer gateways be done with only static routes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, for each one AWS site to site VPN connection, there is only one AWS customer gateway associated to it (this represents the IP address of your peer VPN gateway).

Therefore, as shown in the documentation you have shared [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/s2svpn/vpn-redundant-connection.html), you must define two customer gateways (for each static IP address, which could be the two different interfaces of you peer VPN gateway) to achieve redundancy.